# how to define a form field as a link and display as a link yii

Tags: html, forms, yii

I struggling finding a way to display a database field containing a website address in a form field with the framework Yii.

I've tried    but it does not work.

In clear I'm looking to generate the html

```
<a href="http://example.com">Link to example</a>
```

from the content of the database field  which is a string

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just echo the website address like this?

```
<a href="<?= $model->website ?>">Link to example</a>
```